# Changing outputs with Twitter API

Tags: python, api, twitter

I am trying to make a program that prints how many times a specific keyword has been tweeted about per hour with the Twitter API. I have already fixed the code where it will output the data.

```
from operator import truediv
from urllib import response
import tweepy
import config
import datetime

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=config.BEARER_TOKEN)

query = 'Python'

counts = client.get_recent_tweets_count(query=query,
                                        granularity='hour',
                                        start_time='2022-08-27T13:00:00+05:00',
                                        end_time='2022-08-27T14:00:00+05:00')

for count in counts.data:
    print(count)
```

This code will output the starting time of the search as well as the stopping time and the amount of tweets about said keyword during the hour. However, I am trying to take the actual tweet count number and save it to a file. How can I cut my output down to just the actual tweet number? Here is a sample output of my code.

```
{'end': '2022-08-27T09:00:00.000Z', 'start': '2022-08-27T08:00:00.000Z', 
'tweet_count': 2067}
```

Answer (score 2):

`count` is a `json` object, you just need to parse it:

```
import json
Obj = json.loads(count)
# the result is a Python dictionary
print(Obj['tweet_count'])
```

Comment: Running into a new error now...
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Any ideas?